# Login not working on Heroku with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, heroku

I have a simple PHP script that make a login to desired webpage. It is working OK on my localhost (wamp server), but when I run it on Heroku I get response like this (link: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uilks.png):)

> [image: response]

Script is simple, just like that:

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array( 'user[username]'=>$username, 'user[password]'=>$password)));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;

?>
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Is it something wrong with Heroku or is just luck that code is working OK on my wamp server? I also tried running this script on other free hosting pages but they don't support `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` parameter and so script is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like that page that I was trying to post to has country restricted IP.

Answer (score 0):

The text you're seeing at the top of the page is the header that you requested with :

`curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`

Also, `CURLOPT_POST` is implicit when you use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, not need for it.

You're code should look something like:

```
<?php

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yoursite.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array( 'user[username]'=>$username, 'user[password]'=>$password)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my code but this still forward me to google site when I run from Heroku (link to my app: https://partisrss.herokuapp.com/ ) but it is working without problem on my wamp server.
Maybe there are some setting for curl? I am deploying from dropbox.

Comment: @user1403588 did you fix this problem in Heroku? I have an issue that is returning error 27 when my app run at heroku.

Comment: Hi, there was nothing to fix as page gave country restricted IP so script wasn't working. My other scripts works as intended.